# how can I set $PATH for compiler

Tags: environment-variables

I wrote this

```
# include <stdio.h>
int main () {
printf ("Hello, World! \n");
return 0;
}
```

I tried to compile it using SciTE, it comes this

```
cc -pedantic -Os -c hello.c -o hello.o -std=c99
>Exit code: 0
```

tried to run it, then it comes h:

```
1: ./hello: not found
>Exit code: 127
```

I think the path is not correct:

```
user@user-Aspire-5733Z:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/user/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/opt/csw/bin:/opt/csw/sbin:/opt/csw/gcc3/bin:/usr/sfw/sbin:/usr/sfw/bin:/opt/csw/mysql5/bin:/home/user/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/opt/csw/bin:/opt/csw/sbin:/opt/csw/gcc3/bin:/usr/sfw/sbin:/usr/sfw/bin:/opt/csw/mysql5/bin:/home/user/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/opt/csw/bin:/opt/csw/sbin:/opt/csw/gcc3/bin:/usr/sfw/sbin:/usr/sfw/bin:/opt/csw/mysql5/bin:/bin:/bin
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all after compiling you are running `./hello` but there is no such file named `hello`. Try `ls` to check. You have files like `hello.c` and `hello.o` probably.

Moreover you are compiling with `-c` flag that means source files are Compiled but do not link. See [man gcc](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/gcc.1.html) to know more. So even you try to run `./hello.o` will face another error

```
bash: ./hello.o: Permission denied
```

To have the proper executable (with link) compile without `-c` flag, like

```
cc -pedantic -Os hello.c -o hello.o -std=c99
```

Next run in terminal,

```
./hello.o
```

Now at output you will have, `Hello, World!`

Comment: dear sir can you please be spasific  because i read the man and it does not tell you what to do get the link right thank you

Comment: @user223275 just compile without `-c` flag as I told in the answer. And plz do not say sir.

Comment: Let me know your problem is solved or not?

Comment: My question is solved   Thank you very much   use to be a a baton to click for the feed back.

Answer (score 0):

Note your bash/zsh terminal, it may be different, an $ for example, mine is ->

Please look at the image url in conjunction with the instructions below.

1. From the terminal, **cd** into your working folder
2. Confirm you are in the folder by running **pwd** (optional)
3. Create the file using touch
4. Edit file with whatever editor you use. (**not shown**)
5. There are a number of options to compile, lets go with a simple one.**gcc hello.c -o hello**
6. Use **ls** to view the contents of the folder, as you can see there is a hello. c and hello. hello is the compiled executable file.On my machine I have my terminal colors set, it shows hello in red to show it is an executable.
7. Execute the file, **./hello** note there is no extension. And as you can see the image file it executed.

[image: Terminal view of commands]